Can non-displayed fields of a Django model be altered during custom form validation but before committing model's data?
for the last few weeks I've been working on my first Django project: a database to register all incoming orders from Customers for a generic enterprise. Let's assume that each one of the sale reps could be assigned to a specific Customer for a whole natural year and assignments may vary from one year to another (i.e. agent A assigned to customer A in 2024, whereas in 2025, agent B might be in charge of customer A).
As a start, I decided to use a FK inside Orders model to refer to the associated Product and Customer. At the same time, the Assignments model would also keep a couple of FK to the Customer and Agent tables, so everything could be connected, accessible and data loops were avoided in my relational diagram. Still, this solution was really painful to get some data, specially when I needed to retrieve filtered data for the final templates... so I decided to turn everything upside down and take a different approach:
class Order (models.Model):
    assignment = models.ForeignKey("Assignment", on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    product = models.ForeignKey("Product", on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    order_date = models.DateField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

class Assignment (models.Model):
    assignment_year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey("Customer", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agent = models.ForeignKey("Agent", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['year', 'customer'], name='Primary_Key_Assignment'
            )
        ]
        
class Customer (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    working_time_start = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    working_time_end = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Customers"
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                check = Q(working_time_start__isnull=True, working_time_end__isnull=True)|Q(working_time_start__isnull=False, working_time_end__isnull=False, working_time_start__lte=F('working_time_end')),
                name = 'Wrong working time limits',
            ),
        ]

So Orders are now directly referencing a specific assignments, which I admit it has some pros and cons and I'm not completely confortable with the fact of having the assignment's year and the order's date messing around in the same table due to redundancies and potential inconsistencies.
Once said this, I prefer to hide all this tricky details to the user and would like to have an admin view for the Orders which could hide the assignment FK field, but still would allow the user to select a Customer id. Afterwards, I would pick the Customer's id, the year based on the order's date and build up a valid assignment FK before the register could be saved into the database.
Something like the following:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models import F, CharField
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from .models import Customer, Agent, Product, Order, Assignment

class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    customers_list = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Customer.objects.all())
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        
        form_date = cleaned_data['order_date']
        customer_form = cleaned_data['customers_list']
        cleaned_data['assignment'] = Assignment.objects.get(assignment_year=form_date.year, customer=customer_form.id)
        
        super(OrderForm, self).clean()

        return cleaned_data
    
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'

class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = OrderForm
    fieldsets = (
      ('None', {
          'fields': ( 'customers_list', 'product', 'quantity', 'order_date', 'price', )
      }),
    )

admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)

The clean method presented above complains because I am not including the assignment FK in the form, so I cannot modify it before starting validations at model's level (e.g. CheckConstraints, model's customized clean and save method, if any, etc.).
So my question is: is there any way I could possibly build a valid Order model based on inputs retrieved from the custom Order's form and append my pending assignment as a valid FK before the register is inserted into the database, even when no assignment is displayed to the user?

Pedantry incoming: opinions are plentiful, but clean() is IMO not the place for this logic. I'm going to use save() instead, as I find it makes more logical sense. You can rewrite it for clean() if you like, however.
from django.utils import timezone

class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    customers_list = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Customer.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        exclude = (
            'assignment', # Exclude `assignment` to avoid form validation errors
        )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Create an instance of type Order, but don't commit it to db (yet)
        # This can be easier to work with than form data
        obj: Order = super().save(commit=False)

        # Find or create the assignment
        assignment, _ = Assignment.objects.get_or_create(
            customer=obj.customer, 
            assignment_year=timezone.now().year
        )

        # Add the Order -> Assignment relationship and save the Order instance
        obj.assignment = assignment
        obj.save()

        return obj


Instead of timezone.now().year, you could also do obj.order_date.year if you needed to let the customer pick the date (year) manually.

like this, maybe?
def clean(self):
  cleaned_data = super().clean()
  form_date = cleaned_data['order_date']
  customer_form = cleaned_data['customers_list']
  cleaned_data['assignment'] = Assignment.objects.get(assignment_year=form_date.year, customer=customer_form.id)

  cleaned_data[{field_name}] = self._meta.model.{some_fk_field}
  return cleaned_data


Not exactly. My line right above your proposal was actually aiming to do that, but when I try to add a new order, the execution throws a DoesNotExist exception at that line. That is because 'assignment' is not a field of the form (as I excluded this field from the fieldset defined inside OrderAdmin, to avoid displaying it to the user). So that is the issue: I don't want to display the assignment field, but I want to manually build the data to be inserted as an assignment, along with the rest of Order data to be eventually inserted in the database...

DoesNotExist exception is a problem that occurs when you try to import data that you did not create.
If you want to create and insert data, create and add.

Indeed, the reason for the DoesNotExist exception was that I had no assignment created to associate to the order that I was attempting to create. However, I now get an IntegrityError while creating the order, because the assignment_id cannot be NULL. How (and where) could I take advantage of the data already fufilled in the form in order to fill in the assignment_id prior to this IntegrityError? In other words: could I use the clean_data structure in a custom Order save method to get the associated assignment_id before the error is raised?

Either allow the null or exclude the field from the form.

Allowing nulls may lead to uncontrolled situations that I wouldn't like to deal with in other parts of the code. On the other hand, I believe the assignment field is already excluded, as it was not listed within OrderAdmin's fields list (in fact, that is the reason why I cannot modify it before attempting to store the registry, because there is simply no assignment to modify). What I want is to have it in the list, but hiding it to the user and avoiding an integrity error because the user didn't fill it in, because I plan to assign a value in the background, based on the date and Customer id.

set editable = False

That is indeed avoiding the operator to touch it, yet is still visible and throwing an error because no value was entered by the operator in the form for it...
