How do I filter across multiple model relationships?
My models:
class Order (models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey("Customer", on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    request_date = models.DateField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    @property
    def agent_name(self):
        assignment = Assignment.objects.get(assig_year = self.request_date.year, customer = self.customer)
        if assignment is not None:
            return assignment.sales_agent.name + ' ' + assignment.sales_agent.surname
        else:
            return 'ERROR'

class Company (models.Model):
    pass

class Customer (Company):
    pass

class Assignment (models.Model):
    assig_year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey("Customer", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sales_agent = models.ForeignKey("Agent", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        #unique key year + customer
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['assig_year', 'customer'], name='Primary_Key_Assignment'
            )
        ]

class Employee (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Agent (Employee):
    pass

One assignment relates each customer to a sales agent for a given year. Each customer may have several orders along the year and the agent assigned to the customer is accountable for serving all of them. In one of my views I am displaying all orders by listing their corresponding sales agent, customer, date and price:
def GetOrders(request):
    orders = Order.objects.order_by('-request_date')

    template = loader.get_template('orders.html')
    context = {
        'orders' : orders,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))

orders.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>Agent</th>
          <th>Customer</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for x in orders %}
            <td>{{ x.agent_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.customer.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.request_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.price }}</td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>

I want to add some filtering capability to select the sales agent I'm interested in. I don't know how to deal with relationships to check the sales agent. I tried the agent_name property:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div class="filters">
        <form action="" method="GET">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-3">
              <label>Agent:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" {% if name %} value = "{{ name }}" {% endif %}>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-2" style="padding-top: 2%;">
              <button type="submit" class="btn custom-btn">Filter</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <p/>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>Agent</th>
          <th>Customer</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for x in orders %}
            <td>{{ x.agent_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.customer.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.request_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.price }}</td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>

My view turns to:
def GetOrders(request):
    orders = Order.objects.order_by('-request_date')

    com = request.GET.get('name')
    if com != '' and com is not None:
        orders = orders.filter(Q(agent_name__icontains=com))

    template = loader.get_template('orders.html')
    context = {
        'orders' : orders,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))

But I cannot use it as a filter criterium because it is not a real model field and I get a FieldError:

Cannot resolve keyword 'agent_name' into field


I think we need to solve it by using annotate.
If I look at using objects.get in the agent_name property, it seems to be associated with one object.
Is it possible to have a ForeignKey that connects Assignment and Order?

I also thought about this alternative as access to data is easier. I even tried to implement it, but I think the relationship between models was not so neat/intuitive and I got some other cons in the long run (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78821975/can-non-displayed-fields-of-a-django-model-be-altered-during-custom-form-validat/78823451?noredirect=1#comment139147758_78823451)

class Assignment (models.Model):
    assig_year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey("Customer", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sales_agent = models.ForeignKey("Agent", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        #unique key year + customer
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['assig_year', 'customer'], name='Primary_Key_Assignment'
            )
        ]

class Order (models.Model):
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name="orders")
    request_date = models.DateField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

The reason being:
In the comments, you were worried about data duplication and ER loops. But you already had ER spaghetti and duplication by having a customer connection on both Order and Assignment. While there's nothing wrong with that, it's also somewhat redundant given the constraint that the same sales agent will handle all the customer's orders.
With the above proposed change, we remove the customer FK from Order and instead add an FK Assignment, and we keep the FK from Assignment to Customer. Data duplication is eliminated and ER spaghetti is eliminated (since the dependency chain is now linear):
Order -> Assignment -> Customer

Additionally, the view you need can now be syntactically much simpler:
def GetOrders(request):
    com = request.GET.get('name')
    if com != '' and com is not None:

        # This is the slightly more expensive but maybe more readable version:
        assignments = Assignment.objects.filter(sales_agent=com)
        orders = Orders.objects.filter(assignment__in=assignments)

        # I haven't verified this attempt at a DB optimized version, but I think it's on par:
        orders = Order.objects.select_related('assignment').filter(assignment__sales_agent=com)
    else:
        return Order.objects.none() # Or however you want to handle the case of there being no assignments/orders for a given sales agent

    template = loader.get_template('orders.html')
    context = {
        'orders' : orders,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))

As a bonus, if you ever need a view to see orders per year, for example, you get that for free now, simply invoke assignment.orders. Which works for both sales agents and customers, as both of those entities use Assignment as the middle man.

You can't do this as described because the @property function is set via Python after the query has been executed, it uses the returned query as data for the function. Also, your property makes an SQL call for each agent_name. Not a problem for one agent, but looping through 50 is inefficient.
Likely there is a relationship between orders and assignments, you could connect them via a foreign key as with orders and customers. Then annotate a new field into your queryset:
from django.db.models.functions import Concat
from django.db.models import Value


com = request.GET.get('name')
if com != '' and com is not None:
    #start definition of orders with ( so we can break up the line for readability
    orders = (
        Order.objects.annotate(
            #Combine firstname, space, and last name into new field
            full_name = Concat(
                'order__assignment__sales_agent__name',
                 Value(' '),
                 'order__assignment__sales_agent__surname'
             )
         )
         #filter on our annotated field from the form
         .filter(full_name__icontains=com)
         .order_by('-request_date')
     )

There's no real redundancy between request_date and assig_year. request_date is a date type and the assig_year is acting as a date range. This is fine for making comparisons of a date within a range.
If you add an assignment foreign key to the Order model you could remove customer foreign key from the Order model and use the assignment.customer. This requires you know who the customer is during the order creation process (either by form field or request.user or similar) in order to connect to an assignment.
In your view, once the Order form has been submitted your process might look like this:
if request.method == "POST":
    # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
    form = OrderForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # if the customer is the user
        # customer  = request.user
        # or if the customer is chosen by the form
        customer = form.cleaned_data['customer']
        # now we assign the assignment without asking the user for it
        #- in this example we assume the order date is part of the form
        try:
            assignment = Assignment.object.get(
                customer=customer,
                assig_date = form.cleaned_data['request_date'].year
            )
        except Assignment.DoesNotExist:
            #...Handle error to show no matching assignment
            #  eg return redirect('all_gone_horribly_wrong')
        form.instance.assignment = assignment
        form.save()

Because the form isn't saved and thus the order object isn't created, until after you have created the assignment foreign key link, you don't need to make assignment an optional field in your model.

I'm not sure about the relationship between Order and Assignment, but I confirmed that one Order and Assignment is connected through the agent_name property. You need to modify it through the exact relationship. I connected the Order with Foreignkey to Assignment:
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Order (models.Model):
  customer = models.ForeignKey("Customer", on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
  request_date = models.DateField()
  price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

class Company (models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=24)

class Customer (Company):
  pass

class Assignment (models.Model):
  assig_year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
  customer = models.ForeignKey("Customer", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  sales_agent = models.ForeignKey("Agent", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  order = models.ForeignKey("Order", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="assignment")

class Employee (models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
  surname = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Agent (Employee):
  pass

agent_name constitutes the agent_name value through the name, surname field of the object that meets the conditions of the Assignment object:
@property
def agent_name(self):
    assignment = Assignment.objects.get(assig_year = self.request_date.year, customer = self.customer)
    if assignment is not None:
        return assignment.sales_agent.name + ' ' + assignment.sales_agent.surname
    else:
        return 'ERROR'

Django's filter must have a field used as filter on an object that exists inside Queryset so I added agent_name using the annotate method and then combined the values of the name and surname fields through Concat:
from django.template import loader
from django.db.models import Q, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from .models import Order

# Create your views here.
def GetOrders(request):
    orders = Order.objects.annotate(
        agent_name=Concat('assignment__sales_agent__name', Value(' '), 'assignment__sales_agent__surname')
    ).order_by('-request_date')

    com = request.GET.get('name')
    if com != '' and com is not None:
        orders = orders.filter(Q(agent_name__icontains=com))

    template = loader.get_template('orders.html')
    context = {
        'orders' : orders,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))

In the above state filtering is applied through the name + surname value.
Before applying filtering:

After applying filtering (check the URL GET parameter part):


You should use a GeneratedField for the agent_name field:
from django.db.models import Value as V
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

class Employee (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    agent_name = models.GeneratedField(
        expression = Concat('name', V(' '), 'surname'),
        output_field = models.CharField(max_length = 32 * 2),
        db_persist = True
    )

Now in your view you can filter on agent_name like you would any other field:
def get_orders(request):

    if com := request.GET.get('name'):
        assignment = Assignment.objects.get(agent_name__icontains=com)
        orders = Order.objects.filter(
            customer=assignment.customer, 
            request_date__year=assignment.assig_year,
        )

    else:
        raise Exception('no name')

    context = { 'orders' : orders }
    return render(request, context)


You can't filter on agent_name because it's a property and not a field in your database. Also, using a property that queries the database for each order can be inefficient. Annotate your Order queryset with the agent's name using a Subquery. This allows you to filter directly on agent_name:
First, import the necessary functions at the top of your views file:
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat, ExtractYear

Then, modify your GetOrders view like this:
def GetOrders(request):
    # Subquery to get the agent's full name for each order
    assignments = Assignment.objects.filter(
        customer=OuterRef('customer'),
        assig_year=ExtractYear(OuterRef('request_date'))
    ).annotate(
        agent_full_name=Concat('sales_agent__name', Value(' '), 'sales_agent__surname')
    )

    # Annotate the orders with the agent's name
    orders = Order.objects.annotate(
        agent_name=Subquery(assignments.values('agent_full_name')[:1])
    )

    # Apply the filter if a name is provided
    com = request.GET.get('name')
    if com:
        orders = orders.filter(agent_name__icontains=com)

    orders = orders.order_by('-request_date')

    context = {'orders': orders}
    return render(request, 'orders.html', context)

This way you're adding an agent_name field to each Order object in your queryset, which you can then filter on. It also keeps your database queries efficient. In your template you can still use {{ x.agent_name }} as before.

I personally suggest the way proposed in @Vegard's answer to achieve a simpler and less messy solution and I find it more logical, but if you want to proceed with the way you defined models, you can annotate to each order the agent name who is responsible for the assignment that:

Its customer is the same as the order's customer.
Its 'assig_year' is equal to the order's request_date's year.

To do this I think it will be better to use Coalesce function to return a placeholder at least (because there might be no assignment for an order), so the query goes like:
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, F, Value, CharField, Concat
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

# Now, orders_with_agent will contain Orders annotated with agent_name or 'No agent' if no agent was found.
orders_with_agent = Order.objects.annotate(
    agent_name=Coalesce(
        Subquery(
            Assignment.objects.filter(
                customer=OuterRef('customer'),
                assig_year=OuterRef('request_date__year')
            ).values(
                # Here we concatenate the agent's name and surname
                full_name=Concat(
                    F('sales_agent__name'),
                    Value(' '),
                    F('sales_agent__surname'),
                    output_field=CharField()
                )
            )[:1],  # Get the first matching assignment
            output_field=CharField()
        ),
        Value('No Agent')  # If no matching assignment, return 'No Agent'
    )
)

And note that as we know customer and year are unique together in each assignment, the subquery will contain on record.
